# flutter image_downloader 0.19.2 crash when finished downloading

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using image_downloader 0.19.2 [link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) to download JPEG images to Pictures / subfolder in external memory.

It starts downloading and sometimes suddenly the app crashes and sometimes it just works.

I wasnt able to read any exeption or error!

I'm testing the app on 3 devices and emulator with android versions from 6 to 10.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N960F in profile mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleProfile'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\profile\app-profile.apk (11.7MB).
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53603/Z0HTCq4Xk7c=/ws
D/ViewRootImpl@9967f53[MainActivity]( 5951): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@9967f53[MainActivity]( 5951): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@9967f53[MainActivity]( 5951): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@9967f53[MainActivity]( 5951): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/image_downloader( 5951): RequestResult(id=5626, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59749c25e_1280.jpg, localUri=null, mediaType=null, totalSize=-1, title=, description=)
D/image_downloader( 5951): 0
D/image_downloader( 5951): RequestResult(id=5626, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59749c25e_1280.jpg, localUri=null, mediaType=null, totalSize=-1, title=, description=)
D/image_downloader( 5951): 0
D/image_downloader( 5951): RequestResult(id=5626, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59749c25e_1280.jpg, localUri=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AwesomeWallpapers/awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=172875, title=awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, description=)
D/image_downloader( 5951): 0
D/image_downloader( 5951): RequestResult(id=5626, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59749c25e_1280.jpg, localUri=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AwesomeWallpapers/awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=172875, title=awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, description=)
D/image_downloader( 5951): 0
D/image_downloader( 5951): RequestResult(id=5626, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59749c25e_1280.jpg, localUri=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AwesomeWallpapers/awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=172875, title=awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, description=)
D/image_downloader( 5951): 100
D/image_downloader( 5951): RequestResult(id=5626, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59749c25e_1280.jpg, localUri=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AwesomeWallpapers/awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=172875, title=awesomeWallpaper-7.jpg, description=)
D/AndroidRuntime( 5951): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951): Process: com.example.awesomewallpapers, PID: 5951
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.example.awesomewallpapers (has extras) } in com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader$execute$1@7807408
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl.saveToDatabase(ImageDownloaderPlugin.kt:348)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl.access$saveToDatabase(ImageDownloaderPlugin.kt:200)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl$granted$3.invoke(ImageDownloaderPlugin.kt:301)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl$granted$3.invoke(ImageDownloaderPlugin.kt:200)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader.resolveDownloadStatus(Downloader.kt:171)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader.access$resolveDownloadStatus(Downloader.kt:14)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader$execute$1.onReceive(Downloader.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1646)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5951):    ... 8 more
I/Process ( 5951): Sending signal. PID: 5951 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

and this is my code:

```
  Future<bool> downloadImage(BuildContext context, url, String user, String id) async {
    Toast.show("Downloading...", context,
        duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);

    var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url,
            destination: AndroidDestinationType.directoryPictures
              ..subDirectory("AwesomeWallpapers/$user$id.jpg"))
        .catchError((error) {
      if (error is PlatformException) {
        var path = "";
        if (error.code == "404") {
          print("Not Found Error.");
        } else if (error.code == "unsupported_file") {
          print("UnSupported FIle Error.");
          path = error.details["unsupported_file_path"];
        }
      }
      return false;
    });

    if (imageId != null) {
      openImage(imageId);
      return true;
    }
  }

  void openImage(var imageId) async {
    var path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
    await ImageDownloader.open(path).catchError((error) {
      if (error is PlatformException) {
        if (error.code == "preview_error") {
          print(error.message);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.awesomewallpapers">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="awesomewallpapers"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**UPDATE** i've just noticed that there is a big delay downloading the photos and its recursively calling some code, this lines kept showing in debug

```
D/image_downloader(25908): RequestResult(id=5643, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59e4dc35c_1280.jpg, localUri=null, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=-1, title=, description=)
D/image_downloader(25908): 0
D/image_downloader(25908): RequestResult(id=5643, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59e4dc35c_1280.jpg, localUri=null, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=-1, title=, description=)
D/image_downloader(25908): 0
D/image_downloader(25908): RequestResult(id=5643, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59e4dc35c_1280.jpg, localUri=null, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=-1, title=, description=)
D/image_downloader(25908): 0
D/image_downloader(25908): RequestResult(id=5643, remoteUri=https://pixabay.com/get/57e6d344495ab108f5d084609629317e1638dde5514c704c7d2879d59e4dc35c_1280.jpg, localUri=null, mediaType=image/jpeg, totalSize=-1, title=, description=)
```

after that the app crashed but not one photo was downloaded, seconds later the photos started showing in the directory one by one!

Comment: i think that it is happening because hardcoded name. it is not able to store second time because image is already there. it is only working first time then try to change name second time downloading. give a try by changing name of store file name. let me know what happen

Comment: thanks for replying
i've updated the code and i dont think its because of the name because when the files already exists it changes the name of the new one by adding 1 to it

however. it also crashes while downloading a photo for the first time.

Comment: image_downloade is works on android version 9 or less than

Comment: it will crash on android 10 and greater

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of version mismatch. Try adding legacy support for external storage in the android manifest file.

```
<application
    android:name= ...
    android:label= ...
    android:icon= ...
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```